# Replacing image on server with specific name and till certain limit and if exceed limit should start from first In PHP

Tags: php

I m creating a one form in PHP for upload image in server, That image should upload in 2 folder, in 1st folder image name will go from M1.jpg to M5.jpg, if I upload a 6th image the image name again should be M1.jpg and if I upload 1 more image the name is M2.jpg, etc.

In 2nd folder whatever the image name it should upload with the name and current time.

Now what I have done is that image is upload in both folders, in 1st folder image name upload with M1.jpg to M5.jpg, if upload 6th or 7th image it will replace only 1st image.

How it is possible, that really i don't know. 
Please help out some one Thanks in advance.

Form.php

```
 <div class="sm-col-5">
    <form  action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h2>OFFER IMG</h2>
     <input type="file" name="file">

    </br></br>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" > 
  </form>
  </div>

 <?php 
    $upimg=null;
    if(isset($_GET['upimg'])){
      if ($_GET['upimg']=='' ){
        echo "Please Upload New Image";
      }
      else{
         $upimg=$_GET['upimg'];
        //scan "uploads" folder and display them accordingly

        echo "<img src=\"http://notify/P_Log/".$upimg."\" alt=\"".$upimg."\" >";
      }
    }
 ?>
```

Upload.php

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $folder = "P_Logss";
    $results = scandir('images');
    unset($results[1]);
    $mcount = count($results);
    if($mcount <=5){
      $mname = "M".$mcount++.'.jpg';
    }
    else  {
      $mname = 'M1.jpg';
      $mcount++;
    }
    //$id=uniqid();
    $name     = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $error    = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $size     = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $ext      = strtolower(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    switch ($error) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
            $valid = true;

            if ( !in_array($ext, array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif')) ) {
                $valid = false;
                $response = 'Invalid file extension.';
            }
            if ( $size/2048/2048 > 2 ) {
                $valid = false;
                $response = 'File size is exceeding maximum allowed size.';
            }
            if ($valid) {

                $targetPath =  dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'P_Logss' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$name;
                $targetPath1 =  dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'images' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $mname;

                $upimg=$name;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$targetPath);

                copy($targetPath,$targetPath1); 
                $targetPath =  dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'images' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $mname;
                header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/notify/uploadimg.php?upimg='.$upimg);

                exit;
            }
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            $response = 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.';
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
            $response = 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.';
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            $response = 'No file was uploaded.';
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
            $response = 'Missing a temporary folder. Introduced in PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.3.';
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
            $response = 'Failed to write file to disk. Introduced in PHP 5.1.0.';
            break;
        default:
            $response = 'Unknown error';
        break;
    }

    echo $response;
}
?>
```

Comment: no code = no help

Comment: I think the issue with the if loop..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you are getting the image name, when the count is bigger than 5 you always use 'M1.jpg', you need to use the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

```
$mcount = count($results);
$mname = "M".((($count-1) % 5)+1).'.jpg';
```

In this way if `$mcount` is <=5 you just get that value, if the count is 6 you get 1, with 7 you get 2 and so on.

Note also that `$mcount++` is not needed because you don't have a loop in your code, your code get executed once for each file uploaded and the value is reset in the next execution of the script.

Edit: [online example](http://rextester.com/live/EZJW22974)

Comment: Alberto, Thanks for your reply. i have one doubt forthe 6th image is ok but if i upload image how can we know this image result is 7 or 8 so on. that will not work.

Comment: I don't know if I understand you, but you get that value in `$mcount`, with `$mcount` you get the total number of images in the directory and with `$mcount % 5` you get a value between 1 and 5.

Comment: $result have Maximum 5 image every time than how it will count 6th image. if i upload 6th it should automatic m1.jpg so there is  6th img not aveliable.

Comment: I reread your code and you have another error, you are counting the number of images in "images" which is the folder that can only have 5 images, you need to count the number of images in "P_Logss".

Comment: Ya of course  thanks.. it will works till 9 th images but when i upload 10th image it will make it as M0.jpg, becase the modules operator value became 0.

Comment: yes i got it what you said, now i chk the true directory but not working if i upload 6th image it became direct m2.jpg instead of m1.jpg.                     **fade up because of this issue.**

Comment: Yes, this fails with the 10 image, my bad, I'll correct it. So you need 10 -> 1, 11 -> 2, 12 -> 3 and so on?

Comment: I make a mistake in my previous comment I mean: 6 -> 1, 7 -> 2, 8 -> 3, 9 -> 4, 10 -> 5, 11 -> 1, 12 -> 2 and so on?

Comment: I updated the answer with the code that gets you the desired output, it uses now `((($count-1) % 5)+1)` instead of `($count % 5)`.

Comment: This type is not working at all i tried with your suggestion but it creates only m0.jpg and replace same image every time..

Comment: Read my previous comment, I corrected the answer and now works fine, see online example: http://rextester.com/live/EZJW22974, press "Run it" and see the generated file names up to 35 items.

Comment: I had seen your demo. I think it is working.. but problem may be some other place. bcaz in my file it is not work.

Comment: You replaced `$results = scandir('images');` with `results = scandir('P_Logss');`? Because you need to do that to get the total number of images.

Comment: scan dir also give some other problem.. anyway thanks for your help.. i did that work some other way using databse and now it is working fine..once again thank you Alberto ..

Comment: do u have any idea about in P_Logss folder image upload with original name and current date time i want to add like that type ...